# What is the precedence for bitwise operators (& | ^ ~)

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, operator-precedence

I would assume in java all the bit-wise operators have the same precedence. However in fact the bit-wise operator AND (&) has higher precedence than the bit-wise operator OR (|). See the program below:

public class HelloWorld {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a = 1 | 2 ^ 3 & 5;
    int b = ((1 | 2) ^ 3) & 5;
    int c = 1 | (2 ^ (3 & 5));

    System.out.print(a + "," + b + "," + c);
}
```

}

The result of the above program is 3,0,3.
So it also proves that XOR (^) has higher precedence. Could someone explain a bit why XOR (^) has higher precedence than OR (|) according to the result of the above result? How do they define the precedence?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: The precedences of bit operations are so counter-intuitive that you should always use parentheses.

Comment: @starblue This is a great practice in general. I find that in any moderately complex operation, parentheses speed up understanding even if the cases are not too ambiguous. Conventional math notation is notorious for scrunching everything together, especially since operators are often implicit and thus omitted for things like `2a√b/c3x+y^z4-5`. Plus as mentioned, precedence can vary between language and context.

Comment: BTW, the precedence is most likely inherited from C: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 1):

Because `&` is defined to have higher precedence than `^`, and `^` is defined to have higher precedence than `|`.

[Look at oracle's java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Answer (score 1):

In Java, bitwise operators have different precedences as defined by the Java specification:

> These [bitwise] operators have different precedence, with & having the highest
>   precedence and | the lowest precedence.

So `&` comes before `^` and `^` comes before `|`.